# I changed /etc/sudoers, and now I can't run as sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, root

I messed around with the `sudoers` file without really knowing what I was doing using [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229358/running-commands-from-within-python-that-need-root-access)

Assume I did everything that was in the top answer along with editing it with `vim` and not `visudo`. How do I fix this?

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04, and I didn't set a root password.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest fix is to boot from a Live CD, then mount your local drive and edit or revert to the old `sudoers` file.

1. Boot from a live CD
2. Find your `/` partition. Open a terminal and run `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l` or `blkid` and identify your root (`/`) partition. For this example, I will assume it is `/dev/sda1`.
3. Mount your root partition to a temporary location

   ```
   sudo mkdir /foo
   sudo mount /dev/sda /foo
   ```
4. Now that the partition is mounted, check the `/foo/etc` directory. You probably have a file called `/etc/sudoers~` which is a backup of your `sudoers` file. If so, this will probably solve everything:

   ```
   sudo cp /foo/etc/sudoers~ /foo/etc/sudoers
   ```

   If that doesn't work, just edit the file and revert your changes as best you can (or add it to your question and we can help you out with it). If you introduced lines with a syntax error, remove them or comment them out by adding `#` at the beginning. If you removed the line that granted you sudo powers, it was probably like this (where `sudo` is a group that your user is in, i.e. your username is mentioned on the line in `/etc/group` that begins with `sudo:`)

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```
5. Take the CD out and reboot.

Comment: Not only is this the right answer, but it's a good learning experience - since the OP sounds like a Linux newbie, this makes for a good illustration of how to recover after doing something bad to your root partition.  And, fortunately, messing up /etc/sudoers is a pretty easy "something bad" to recover from.

Comment: @godlygeek: It's a good answer, but a better answer is *switch to `root` and fix it,* which, given the distributions' ridiculous user default user policy, is impossible. So terdon has provided what is, unfortunately, the best answer possible.